# No SIM card detected after installing new ROM

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, sim-card

I probably did some mistake which I don't know how to solve. After I installed a new ROM I get message:

> Slot 1: No SIM card detected
>
> Slot 2: No SIM card detected

„SIM management“ is inoperable, „Sim Toolkit“ can't launch because it cann't detect SIM card.
Calling emergency number gets „Out of service area“.
Everything else works just fine (including WiFi) except I can't get SIM card to work and get signal.

**Information about the phone:**
FEITENG GT H9500
Android version 4.2.1
Baseband version MOLY.WR8.W1248.MD.WG.MP.V6.P4
Kernel version 3.4.5 root@android #1
Build number drx_0.1
I have both IMEIs and IMEI VS visible
CWM v6.0.2.8

**What I did prior to loss of SIM card functionality:**
-   Made backup of „user data“, cca. 350MB
-   Rooted the phone using instructions as follows:
1.Download usb driver ----> mirrorcreator.com/files/RJDKYXRH/ and open Driver_Auto_Installer_v1.1236.00.rar and run install.bat it install driver automatically 
2. Plug your phone to pc
3.Download this file ----> [www.mirrorcreator.com/files/09XPAELB](http://www.mirrorcreator.com/files/09XPAELB) open Motochopper_Auto_Root.rar and run run.bat your phone has root

- Downloaded ROM update FEITENG H9500 - Update - 06/01/2013 and Recovery from:
  [www.needrom.com/mobile/feiteng-h9500-3](http://www.needrom.com/mobile/feiteng-h9500-3)/
- Followed instructions: 
  Unpack FlashTools, and Click on Flash_tool.exe
  Select a the MT6589_Android_scatter_emmc.txt in Recovery
  Turn off your phone, remove the battery.
  Press F9 (or hit Download button) and connect your phone into the computer via USB data cable.
  The process will start and a red progress bar will appear after color purple, yellow.
  And green circles display
- Installed ROM from SD card ( in CWM)
- NOTE: I downloaded only update file H9500_DRX_03, and in „Flashtool“ only „Recovery" option was checked. I don't remember was the SIM card inside during installation of the ROM (probably wasn't).
- FlashTool V3.1252.1.sn104
- I installed that ROM with most of its options and wiped data and cache before installation.
- ROM got installed and after restart I lost SIM card visibility.
- No external damage was done to SIM slot.

**What I tried to fix it:**
-       Both SIM slots are not damaged, this happened just after reboot
-   Tried different SIM cards from anothers phones
-   Tried my SIM card on other phones to make sure that it works
-   Format eMMC
-   At „factory mode“ Detect SIM test failed
-   Did wipe data/cache several times before and during attempts to install different roms
-   Tried installing another ROMs (with SIM card in and without), all with „clean install“.
-   During installation (download and upgrade) of ROMs from FlashTool selected all options (preloader,mbr,ebr1,uboot etc.)
-   Tried installing „original“ ROM from: needrom.com/mobile/feiteng-h9500
However it said „Installation aborted“ but I see the ROM was installed.

**What I did wrong from what I know:**
- I didn't backed up old ROM that I got with my phone
- I did „Download“ with update ROM v3 and not the initial version
- I didn't do „download“ the first version and then „Upgrade“ the rest of upgrades (I don't know is that relevant)
- I did not selected all options (preloader,mbr,ebr1,uboot etc.) in Flashtool except for „recovery“ when I first installed the ROM if that is relevant

So, I don't konw is there any relevant information I can provide since I honestly don't know
 what can be relevant and what not.
Is there something that can help with this?
Thank You for Your time.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: http://www.movilesdualsim.com/threads/rom-drx-v0-4-jb-4-2-1-feiteng-h9500-star-n9500.32072/ That is Spanish page, I don't know Spanish, I never translated it completely. There is one line where it points out that there are some problems with loader and recovery so they made modification. I Applyed modification "Actualización rom base" ... uploaded DRX4 and it worked like charm. Thank You for your time.